# Traceback (most recent call last): (cannot copy tree '%s': not a directory" % src)

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

I want to program a small script using python which goes into my google drive folder and copies all the files there to a folder with the current date. So fromDirectory is obviously the directory where my program should copy the files from and todirectory is a directory on a extern hdd. I already check if the paths are correct and I'm sure that they are. Unfortunately a error raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    copy_tree(fromDirectory, toDirectory)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 124, in copy_tree
    "cannot copy tree '%s': not a directory" % src)
distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: cannot copy tree 'C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Google Drive': not a directory
```

Code:

```
import time
import sys
import shutil
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
import os
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()

fromDirectory = "C:/Users/Micheal/Desktop/Google Drive"
toDirectory = "S:/" + today.strftime('%d%m%Y') 

copy_tree(fromDirectory, toDirectory)
```

Hope for help!

EDIT:
**I was stupid:**

I wrote my program on PC1 and now tested it on PC2, so I didn't notice that there really was a Google Drive folder on the desktop of PC1 but not on the desktop of PC2 (just a shortcut to the Google Drive folder). For PC2 the correct path is "C:/Users/Michael/Google Drive".

Comment: So Google Drive is a real folder and not a link or whatever to google's online storage cloud thing?

Comment: that was the problem. See my question edit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the `' '` in 'Google Drive', try renaming it to 'Google_Drive' or 'Google-Drive'.
You can also try to replace `"C:/Users/Micheal/Desktop/Google Drive"` with `"C:/Users/Micheal/Desktop/'Google Drive'"`, as that is how it works in bash scripts, but I can't guarantee it'll work in that case

Edit:
You can also add a `\` before the space, so `Google Drive` becomes `Google\ Drive`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately none of the three options worked. Other ideas?

Comment: Try removing the space (' ') all together. Change the name of the google drive folder to `Google-Drive` and do the same in your code

Comment: Or even maybe swap out `"C:/Users/Micheal/Desktop/Google Drive"` for `'C:/Users/Micheal/Desktop/"Google Drive"'` - its weird but it just may work

Comment: Yeah, but I've already tested it. (I even swapped to GoogleDrive). The weird thing about all this is that it all works if I replace Google Drive with Testfolder (and creating Testfolder on the Dektop)